# How do I switch which weapon I am using in each slot?

Tags: assassins-creed-2

When you buy a new weapon it replaces whatever you were currently carrying of the same type, but I cannot seem to find a way to switch *back* to previous weapons.

The shops just have previous items flagged as "already owned" (or purchased, can't remember the text at the moment) and the inventory only seems to list my current selections.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to Monteriggioni in Mario's house.

In the room at your left, you'll find all your armors and weapons. You can get equip whichever you want here.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense, I'll have a look for it this evening :) Also, is this signposted in the game at all (ie, did I miss the bit where I get told this)?

Comment: No I don't think there is any clue of this in the game... and can be really annoying when you lost some weapon during a battle. BTW: hidden blade for the win :P

Comment: O_o So you can be disarmed? I've probably not got far enough to meet the right type of enemy yet, but I'll have to keep an eye out for that...

Comment: Yes it happens sometimes. And sometimes it's hard to find your weapon through the pile of corpses you made and sometimes you just run away...

Comment: I think it does tell you about this the first time you enter that room.

Comment: Yeah, I vaguely remember at some point being told to go explore after arriving at Monteriggioni, and when I entered that room there was an explanation about the room.

Comment: Well, found it, clearly I didn't explore enough, it's pretty obvious when you know it's there but needed a bit more signposting imo. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, just to be clear, when you buy a weapon or armour that replaces one you're carrying/wearing, the one you already had teleports to Mario's villa.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner It's been 8 years since I wrote that answer, but I think that's how it works yes.